# Где хранить квесты для игры

Tags: php

Добры день! Собираюсь писать онлайн игру (HTML + CSS + PHP + SQL, БЕЗ JS), всё тщательно продумываю, собираю графику и т.п. Возник вопрос где хранить квесты? В php файле или БД? Ведь квест может быть разный, от сбора предметов, до разговора с человеком и т.п. Как сделать? Хранить в виде массива с различными элементами и проверками, или как то иначе? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: А чем хранение данных квестов отличается от хранения каких-нибудь других данных? И еще, **БЕЗ JS** создать что-либо достойное, вам вряд ли удастся, но это ИМХО.

Comment: Вопрос не в использовании JS, отличается тем, что имеет непредсказуемые условия.

Comment: nosql вас спасет ? без js вы загнули

Answer (score 3):

Ну для начала предлагаю сесть и продумать какие варианты квестов могут быть. Как я понял, квесты могут появляться уже после запуска игры - а значит лучше это дело *хранить в БД*, чтобы каждый раз не идти в код игры, т.к. каждое изменение необходимо тщательно проверить...

После того как определишь, какие квесты могут быть, какие входные и выходные данные, предлагаю *сделать модель*, которая может это дело хранить,  и по этой модели уже *создавать структуру БД*.

---

Каждое действие заносишь под своим идентификатором, который уже привязываешь к логике в php. Например:

1. **Поговорить с человеком** = 1
2. **Собрать зелье** = 2
3. **Накопить золото** = 3
4. **Добавить человека** = 4

и дополнительный параметр Value

1. Для разговора с человеком, к примеру id Человека / Существа
2. Например массив зельев: Array([id зелья]=[кол-во], [id предмета] = [кол-во])
3. Количество золота, например 500
4. Так же как и в пункте 1

Ну и, чтобы не получились магические id, прописываешь в php константы имен:

```
    define("ACTION_TALK", 1); 
    define("ACTION_COLLECT", 2);
    // и т.д.
```

ID | ACTION | VALUE

Comment: Например так: Нужно убить животное; Нужно поговорит с человеком; Нужно собрать два зелья; Нужно накопить 500 монет; Нужно добавить друга и т.п, Это мне придётся для каждого условия создавать колонку? Или как.
ID | TEXT | FRIENDS | POISON | WAPEN | COIN  - Так чтоли??

Comment: например, для каждого действия определяешь свой id, а дальше значение, в ответе щас добавлю пример.

Comment: спасибо! Учту!

Answer (score 1):

Интересная задумка, но не менее интересные инструменты вы предлагаете для разработки онлайн-игры. Почему бы не посмотреть в сторону flash и, к примеру сервиса Player.IO для многопользовательских игр. По вопросу: возможно лучше создать отдельную таблицу в бд:

(id, тот кто дал задание , тот кому надо сдать задание, сроки выполнения, условие выполнения, условие неудачи).

А задания брать по идентификатору как предложил IVsevolod, заранее объявив их как константы

Comment: спасибо! Учту!